# Raspberry Pi 2B not powering up

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues

I've been using RPi 2B for two months and it was running smoothly. Today when I connected to power supply, it does not boot. The red LED is still OFF, ACT is ON but not blinking.

I thought the problem is with the SD card, but whenever I power the board, the Broadcom IC heats up and some sound can be heard. 
Edit:
The sound is similar to what we hear from a power socket when the plug connected is not fitted well or from a loose connection. I don't know from which part of the sound comes. But the board heats up near the micro usb port. There's no smell of burning; one of the components got fried.

Comment: This is actually a really broad question. Possibilities include but not limited to electrical problems, power surges, lightning strikes, or paranormal activity.

Comment: Define heated up and as the Pi as no moving parts I am curious what type of sound you are hearing.

Comment: @PandaLion98 +1 for the paranormal activity explanation. I would add the divine aka releasing the magic blue smoke

Comment: Hi Anand, and welcome to SE Raspberry Pi... Is the sound coming from your power supply, i.e. is it a 50/60 Hz hum? Or, if you are saying that the IC heats up, do you mean that it gets really hot and you can hear a sizzling sound? If it is the latter, then is it accompanied by a smell of burning? If so, that would suggest that IC is fried and the solder/resin is melting... As @SteveRobillard says, please edit your question and clarify "heats up" and the sound source.

Comment: I've closed this question until you *edit in* (not add comments about) the details requested above.  When you've done so,  leave a comment here "@goldilocks".

Comment: @goldilocks I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

At this point I'd say it's fairly safe to say that this parrot is no more. I'd even go so far as to say that it's a fire hazard if it's heating up and making noises.

It should be properly disposed of (recycled) and replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Although your symptoms sound very sinister, there is a chance that you've blown the main [polyfuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse), which I would assume is not far from the microUSB jack.

So you could try leaving it for a few days to let that reset and then plugging it in again.  But as Jacobm points out, it is most likely trash.

Comment: I powered it today. Now both red and green LEDs are ON. Red LED lights up 5-6 seconds after the green one. Whenever red LED lights, the creepy sound goes off. And the Broadcom IC heats up quickly. There's a 0.04v drop across the polyfuse.